# WSO2 Android App Deployment: Complete action using

Tags: android, wso2

Good evening Everyone,

When I try to deploy an android application from either the Store or the WSO2 Enterprise Mobility App Management area the tablet I am working on prompts me to "Complete action using" Google Play Store or Mobogenie.

I am glad it is finally prompting me with these options as I feel I am making progress.

Tablet Specifications:

Model Number: rk30sdk
Android Version: 4.1.1
Kernel Version: 3.0.8+
Build Number: RK30_ANDROID4.1.1-SDK-v1.00.00, rk30sdk-eng4.1.1 JRO03H20121130.195831 release-keys

I am able to wipe, lock, and set wifi configuration on the device; just cannot figure out how to get an app to install. Originally this device was not-rooted; I went ahead and rooted it, same result.

Thank you for your assistance,

Thomas

Comment: Good morning, 

I forgot to add the server information; I am leaning towards a problem on the tablet.

Operating System: Windows 7 
Java: Java SE Development Kit 7 Update 72 (32 and 64 bit)
Web Server: XAMPP 1.8.3 (Apache 2.4.7)

Thank you, 




Thomas

Comment: Good evening, 

I am also testing with Meraki and facing the same issue. So it isn't the WSO2 system; but something with the tablet. Does anyone have any suggestions? I deploy / push an app from the dashboard and a Window on the tablet appears "Complete action using" and the options are Google Play Store or Mobogenie. 

Thank you for your time, 




Thomas